# How to change AWS ELB status to InService?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

A WordPress application is deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk that has a load balancer. I see sometimes there is ELB 5XX error. To make the instance OutOfService for the higher number of unhealthy threshold count, I set Unhealthy Threshold to 10. But sometimes health check fails and health is Severe. I get sometimes the error "% of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx". I checked the ELB access logs and sometimes request get the timeout (504) error and after a consecutive number of 504, ELB makes the instance OutOfService. I am trying to fix which request is failing.

What I don't know, is it possible to make the instance "InService" as quickly as possible. Because sometimes instance is OutOfService for 2-3 hours, which is really bad. Is there any good way to handle this situation. I am really in trouble with this situation. Looks like after the service is out, I have nothing to do. I am relatively new to AWS. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue:

1) HTTP 504 means timeout. The resource that the load balancer is accessing on your backend is failing to respond. Determine what the path for the healthcheck from the AWS console.

2) In your browser verify that you can access the healthcheck path going around the load balancer. This may mean temporarily assigning an EIP to the EC2 instance. If the load balancer healthcheck is "/test/myhealthpage.php" then use "http://REPLACE_WITH_EIP/test/myhealthpage.php". For HTTPS listeners use https in your path.

3) Debug why the path that you specified is timing out and fix it.

Note: Healthcheck paths should not be to pages that do complicated tests or operations. A healthcheck should be a quick and simple GO / NO GO type of page.

Comment: 1) Health check protocol is TCP and port 80.

2) I already have public IP for my ec2 instance, through which the application is not accessible. My domain is from GoDaddy, so I set up AWS nameservers to GoDaddy. I don't know if that's the reason for the not accessible situation. But I created A records, which pointing domain name to the load balancer.

3) I regularly monitor ELB logs and apache access logs. I found some of the endpoints are getting 5XX errors. Sometimes there is 500 and sometimes 504.


Anything to do if EB health is severe? As the application goes down for 2-3 hours.